# Docker and Rabbitmq: ECONNREFUSED between containers

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, seneca

I am trying to setup separate docker containers for rabbitmq and the consumer for the container, i.e., the process that would listen on the queue and perform the necessary tasks.  I created the yml file, and the docker file.

I am able to run the yml file, however when I check the docker-compose logs I see where there are ECONNREFUSED errors.

**NewUserNotification.js:**

```
require('seneca')()
    .use('seneca-amqp-transport')
    .add('action:new_user_notification’, function(message, done) {
        … 

        return done(null, {
        pid: process.pid,
        status: `Process ${process.pid} status: OK`
    })
    .listen({
        type: 'amqp',
        pin: ['action:new_user_notification’],
        name: 'seneca.new_user_notification.queue',
        url: process.env.AMQP_RECEIVE_URL,
        timeout: 99999
    });
```

**error message in docker-compose log:**

```
    {"notice":"seneca: Action hook:listen,role:transport,type:amqp failed: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5672.","code":
    "act_execute","err":{"cause":{"errno":"ECONNREFUSED","code":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1",
    "port":5672},"isOperational":true,"errno":"ECONNREFUSED","code":"act_execute","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1",
    "port":5672,"eraro":true,"orig":{"cause":{"errno":"ECONNREFUSED","code":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1",
    "port":5672},"isOperational":true,"errno":"ECONNREFUSED","code":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":5672},
    "seneca":true,"package":"seneca","msg":"seneca: Action hook:listen,role:transport,type:amqp failed: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5672.",
    "details":{"message":"connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5672","pattern":"hook:listen,role:transport,type:amqp","instance":"Seneca/…………/…………/1/3.4.3/-“,
    ”orig$":{"cause":{"errno":"ECONNREFUSED","code":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":5672},"isOperational":true,
"errno":"ECONNREFUSED","code":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":5672}
```

**sample docker-compose.yml file:**

```
version: '2.1'
services:
 rabbitmq:
    container_name: "4340_rabbitmq"
    tty: true
    image: rabbitmq:management
    ports:
      - 15672:15672
      - 15671:15671
      - 5672:5672
    volumes:
      - /rabbitmq/lib:/var/lib/rabbitmq
      - /rabbitmq/log:/var/log/rabbitmq
      - /rabbitmq/conf:/etc/rabbitmq/
account:
    container_name: "account"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Account/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    links:
      - "mongo"
      - "rabbitmq"
    depends_on:
      - "mongo"
      - "rabbitmq"
new_user_notification:
    container_name: "app_new_user_notification"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Account/dev.newusernotification.Dockerfile
    links:
      - "mongo"
      - "rabbitmq"
    depends_on:
      - "mongo"
      - "rabbitmq"
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "rabbitmq:5672", "-t", "90", "--", "node", “newusernotification.js"]
```

**amqp connection string:** 
(I tried both ways, with and without a user/pass)
amqp://username:password@rabbitmq:5672

I added the link attribute to the docker-compose file and referenced the name in the .env file(rabbitmq).  I tried to run the NewUserNotification.js file from outside the container and it started fine.  What could be causing this problem?  Connection string issue?  Docker-Compose.yml configuration issue?  Other?

Comment: What's passed as `process.env.AMQP_RECEIVE_URL`?

Comment: How are you configuring rabbitmq? Are you creating a new user/pw and vhost?

Comment: The process.env.AMQP_RECEIVE_URL points to a variable in the .env file that uses the amq connection string listed above.

Comment: No.  It is currently using the guest account.

Comment: Now, I did read some doc. outlining how to links are getting deprecated in the future but I am not sure how to use networks option.  I would assume that I need a configuration where everything is on the same network, but am unsure of how to set that up.

Comment: @user1790300, docker-compose automatically put everything on the same network. Containers can talk to each other using their container names (i.e. http://<container-name>:<port>) https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems the environment variable `AMQP_RECEIVE_URL` is  not constructed properly. According to error log the listener is trying to connect to localhost(127.0.0.1) which is not the rabbitmq service container IP. Find the modified configurations for a working sample.

1 docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.1'
services:
 rabbitmq:
    container_name: "4340_rabbitmq"
    tty: true
    image: rabbitmq:management
    ports:
      - 15672:15672
      - 15671:15671
      - 5672:5672
    volumes:
      - ./rabbitmq/lib:/var/lib/rabbitmq
 new_user_notification:
    container_name: "app_new_user_notification"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ./un.env
    links:
      - rabbitmq
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "rabbitmq:5672", "-t", "120", "--", "node", "newusernotification.js"]
```

2 un.env

`AMQP_RECEIVE_URL=amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672`

Note that I've passed the `AMQP_RECEIVE_URL` as an environment variable to `new_user_notification` service using `env_file` and got rid of the `account` service

3 Dockerfile

```
FROM node:7
WORKDIR /app
COPY newusernotification.js /app
COPY wait-for-it.sh /app
RUN npm install --save seneca
RUN npm install --save seneca-amqp-transport
```

4 `newusernotification.js` use the same file in the question.

5 [wait-for-it.sh](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/blob/master/wait-for-it.sh)

Comment: Can you use a .env file for node in docker?

Comment: @user1790300 Yes you can. Please find the documentation with examples here https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#substituting-environment-variables-in-compose-files

Comment: @user1790300 updated docker-compose.yml and added the un.env file

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that your RabbitMQ service is not fully up, at the time the connection is attempted from the consuming service.

If this is the case, in Docker Compose, you can `wait` for services to come up using a container called [dadarek/wait-for-dependencies](https://github.com/dadarek/docker-wait-for-dependencies).

**1).** Add a new service `waitforrabbit` to your docker-compose.yml

```
waitforrabbit:
  image: dadarek/wait-for-dependencies
  depends_on:
    - rabbitmq 
  command: rabbitmq:5672
```

**2).** Include this service in the `depends_on` section of the service that requires RabbitMQ to be up.

```
depends_on: 
  - waitforrabbit
```

**3).** Startup compose

```
docker-compose run --rm waitforrabbit
docker-compose up -d account new_user_notification
```

Starting compose in this manner will essentially wait for RabbitMQ to be fully up before the connection from the consuming service is made.

Comment: It's not a possibility  'cause wait-for-it.sh is exactly handling this case https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it

Comment: @Anuruddha why isn't this a possibility?